# How to grant user create and delete index in mysql?

Tags: mysql

As title.
I create a new user in mysql, and grant this user CURD permission.When I create an index for a table, mysql warning '1142-ALTER command denied to user .......'.
How can I do to grant user create or delete index?

Comment: ALTER is another privilege that you need to grant for that user.  Extremely granular controls are normal for most databases as we DBA as just that anal.

Comment: Thank for your answer!You are right.

Answer (score 0):

I try to do something.

> grant alter on database.table to 'user'@'IP-address';

This command works.